Bazel: handling libraries in a multirepo environment
I'm looking for some advice on managing libraries in a multirepo environment. At the company where I work, we have two custom "build systems," and, to be honest, both are pretty bad. I've been given the daunting task of improving this setup.
We operate in a multirepo environment where some repositories contain libraries and others are microservices that depend on these libraries. Most of our code is written in Python. Here's an overview of our current local environment structure:

├── python_applications
│   ├── APP1
│   │   ├── requirements.txt
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── test
│   └── APP2
│       ├── requirements.txt
│       ├── src
│       └── test
└── python_libraries
    ├── A
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   ├── src
    │   └── test
    └── B
        ├── requirements.txt
        ├── src
        └── test

Note:
A, B, APP1, and APP2 are in separate Git repositories.

B depends on A (along with other pip dependencies)

APP1 requires A.

APP2 requires A.

While researching more standardized solutions, I came across Bazel, and it seems promising. However, I could use some guidance on a few points:

Should APP1 and APP2 have its own MODULE and put only BUILD in A or B, or should there be a different structure? Note: every "module" have a requiremets.txt file.

If APP2 uses Python 3.11 and APP1 uses Python 3.8, but both depend on A, how should I handle this situation with Bazel?

How should I use Bazel in a local development environment, particularly when I need to work with local versions of libraries that I'm actively modifying (referring to git_repository(...))?

What is the best way to utilize Bazel in our CI/CD pipeline to produce Docker images for testing, staging, and production?


Any tips, insights or resources for learning would be greatly appreciated!

Any tips so why not use pip and pytest?
